# What type of Cinnelli frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Can you help? I have just been given a bike as payment for some repairs I carried out for a friend. Not sure what frame type it is, I know that it's a Cinnelli with a Campagnolo gear set and brakes as well as 700c rims in black. On the bottom crank casing it has some letters and numbers I think they are grey?brey? Followed by what I think is 228298-84. Sorry for the vaugeness.

Is it vintage? Rare? Any idea of value at all?

It is very clean a few little spots 
Would love some info on it if you could please

Please let me know how to send you pictures, can't find where you can create an  attachment.

Comment: You don’t have enough reputation to embed images. Upload images to imgur, add urls to your post  and someone  will edit it to embed them

Comment: Try [contacting Cinelli](https://www.cinelli-usa.com/contact-us/) and see if they have any info.

Comment: If its a real cinelli then it could have some value.  A photo would let us help you date it.  The upload site of choice is https://imgur.com/ but post it anywhere and we'll sort it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close, for now, as the question is unanswerable without pictures. If you edit the post to include links to them, I'll happily vote to reopen.

Comment: @stevegreen don't take this personally.  Add some more info and the question will be submitted for reopening.  Describing your bike without a photo is like describing a rash to a doctor.  Pictures really are worth a thousand words.

Comment: Also, now you have 11 rep points you can click "edit" and then use the "upload" button which is above the text area.